# Split array based on two delimiters using a regular expression and know the splitted character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to separate a string based on `#` and `.` and put the substring into an associative array depending on which character it matched on.

For example if I have:

```
"one#two.three"
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
e["none"] = "one";
e["period"] = "two";
e["hash"] = "three";
```

The main problem I have is I can't figure out how to tell if it matched on a `#` or `.`.

I don't need to use a regular expression, I just assumed it would be the best way.

EDIT: I am assuming that there will only be one of each. So the input:

```
one.two.three
```

would be invalid

Comment: So what happens with `"one.two.three"`?

Comment: I am assuming that there will only be one of each.

Comment: Play around with this: `"one.two#three".match(/^(?:(.*?)\.(.*?)#(.*))|(?:(.*?)#(.*?)\.(.*))$/);`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var e = {};
var s = "one#two.three";
var parts = s.match(/[.#]|[^.#]+/g);

var state = "none";
for(var i=0; i<parts.length; ++i) {
    var item = parts[i];
    if (item == '.') {
        state = 'period';
    } else if (item == '#') {
        state = 'hash';
    } else {
        e[state] = item;
    }
}    
console.log(e);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H9j6U/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<!--
    Split string with multiple deliminators
    example: . and #
-->
<?php
    // For PHP
    $string = 'one#two.three.four';
    $output = preg_split("/(#|\.)/", $string);
    print_r($output);
?>

<script>
    // For JS
    // Just a modified version of Lee's code to create index array
    var storage = [];
    var string = "one#two.three.four";
    var parts = string.match(/[.#]|[^.#]+/g);
    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
        var item = parts[i];
        if (item != '.' && item != '#') {
            storage[storage.length] = item;
        }
    }
    console.log(storage);
</script>
```